# Apache is not interpreting python files

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, mod-wsgi

So, I followed this tutorial on Ubuntu 14.04 
http://jee-appy.blogspot.in/2015/04/deploy-django-project-on-apache-using.html
Only thing I changed is instead of his example repository,I have used mine.
And I was getting error

> Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Then, I edited my myproject.conf file
Change made - WSGIScriptAlias /myproject /var/www/myproject.wsgi
So, I'm having output Index of/ then directory and file name. it's not interpreting my python files.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and I modified my wsgi file to look like this:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/var/www/html/YOURAPP/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

path = '/var/www/html/YOURAPP/YOURAPP/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'YOURAPP.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Hope this helps